# $P \otimes P(\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^{2d};x=y \right\})=1$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $P$ a probability measure on $(\mathbb{C}^d,B(\mathbb{C}^d)),$ such that for all $E \in B(\mathbb{C}^d),P(E)$ is $0$ or $1.$ Let $X=\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^{2d};x=y \right\}.$

Prove that $P \otimes P(X)=1.$

$P \otimes P(X)=\int_{\mathbb{C}^d}P(\left\{x \right\})dP(x),$ $P(\left\{x \right\})$ could be $0$ or $1$, any suggestions how to continue?

Comment: I would show that $P=\delta_a$ for some $a\in \mathbb{C}^d$, then we get the desired conclusion.

Comment: For that one first shows that there exists some $R>0$ such that $P([-R,R])=1$. Then you start bisecting this interval such that the new smaller interval still has measure equal to $1$ and then conclude.

Comment: You seem not to be convinced by my answer. What should I improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you the case where we have $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}^d$ (the idea is the same). We have
$$ 1 =\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} P([-R,R]).$$
As $P([-R,R])\in \{0,1\}$ we get that there exists some $R>0$. Now we define recursively $[a_0,b_0]:=[-R,R]$ and
$$ [a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}]:= \begin{cases}
[a_n, (a_n+b_n)/2],& \text{if } P([a_n, (a_n+b_n)/2])=1,\\
[(a_n+b_n)/2, b_n],& \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Note that we have $P([a_n, b_n])=1$. We have for $a=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n$
$$1=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P([a_n, b_n])= P(\{a\}).$$
Thus, $P=\delta_a$.

Then we have
$$ (P\otimes P)(\{(a,a)\})=1$$
and we get the desired claim.